# Sequelize include - Don't include (remove) pivot data

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using the Sequelize package for node. I have a typical include on man to many relationship.

```
Item.findAll({
    include: {model: Blah: as 'blahs'}
});
```

All works well but it returns the set with the pivot data on each sub item. I don't need it. Is there any way to disable it or to specify the pivot fields needed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found my answer:

```
{model: Model, as: 'model', through: {attributes: []}}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not very clear what you are looking for but can you try adding raw:true

```
Item.findAll({
    include: {model: Blah, raw: true}
});
```

can you post the result you got vs result you want