# How to query on nested object with Sequelize, but don't include that in response?

Tags: sequelize.js

I have two models in Sequelize and a relation many-to-many between them:

```
StatusManifestation = db.define('status_manifestation', {/* attributes */});
Profile = db.define('profile', {/* attributes */});

StatusManifestation.belongsToMany(Profile, { through: 'status_manifestation_profile', foreignKey: 'status_manifestation_id' });
Profile.belongsToMany(StatusManifestation, { through: 'status_manifestation_profile', foreignKey: 'profile_id' });
```

I want to find all StatusManifestation that relates to a Profile with a certain id.

What I'm trying to do is this:

```
StatusManifestation.findAll({ include: [{ model: Profile, where: { id: 'this_is_an_id' } }] })
```

But the response is a StatusManifestation model with a profiles attribute containing the profiles.

How can I do this query without returning the profiles attribute?

PS: This answer didn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/33826540/8255874

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

```
StatusManifestation.findAll({ 
  include: [{ 
    model: Profile, 
    where: { id: 'this_is_an_id' },
    attributes: { 
      exclude: [attributes to exclude]
    } 
  }] 
})
```